# is page array only loading script on first class

Tags: php, wordpress

Any idea why this is only loading a script on the first class `brand` and not on `home`?

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    //nothing to do here

} if ( is_page( array( 'brand-contact', 'home' ) ) ) { ?>
    //script goes here

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is_page('home')` isn't the function you're looking for. Try `is_home()` instead.

```
if ( is_page('brand-contact') || is_home() ) { ?>
    //script goes here

<?php }
```

Comment: close! instead of `is_home`, `is_front_page` worked.